# How to Receive data on AVR SPI

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr, spi

I'm working on an AVR to learn it. my question is that `SPI0_exchangeData` send a receive data at same time with a same clock. Now I want that while receiving data it should add 1 to the array that I can see that this is the data I receive.

**NOTE: I'm not native speaker of English so I read the datasheet and read some online article but no success.**

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void SPI0_init(void);

void LTCSelect(void);
void LTCDeselect(void);
uint8_t SPI0_exchangeData(uint8_t data);

void SPI0_init(void)
{
    PORTA.DIR |= PIN4_bm; /* Set MOSI pin direction to output (output to LTC2983) */
    PORTA.DIR &= ~PIN5_bm; /* Set MISO pin direction to input (input form LTC2983) */
    PORTA.DIR |= PIN6_bm; /* Set SCK pin direction to output (output to LTC2983) */
    PORTA.DIR |= PIN7_bm; /* Set CS pin direction to output  (output to LTC2983) */
    
    SPI0.CTRLA = SPI_CLK2X_bm /* Enable double-speed */
                | SPI_DORD_bm /* LSB is transmitted first */
                | SPI_ENABLE_bm /* Enable module */
                | SPI_MASTER_bm /* SPI module in Master mode */
                | SPI_PRESC_DIV16_gc; /* System Clock divided by 16 */
}

uint8_t SPI0_exchangeData(uint8_t data)
{
    
    SPI0.DATA = data;
    while (!(SPI0.INTFLAGS & SPI_IF_bm))  /* waits until data is exchanged*/
    {
        
    }

    return SPI0.DATA;
}


void LTCSelect(void)
{
    PORTA.OUT &= ~PIN7_bm; // Set SS pin value to LOW
}

void LTCDeselect(void)
{
    PORTA.OUT |= PIN7_bm; // Set SS pin value to HIGH
}
void sendArray(uint8_t data[], uint8_t length) {
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        SPI0_exchangeData(data[i]);
    }
}
// Suppose we have an array named buffer
uint8_t buffer[] = { 10, 20, 30};


int main(void)
{

    SPI0_init();
    while(1){
            
            LTCSelect();
            sendArray(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            LTCDeselect();  
    }

}
```

Comment: There's no need to re-ask the same question.  You've edited the original, so it will go into a reopen review queue.

Comment: You cannot resize a statically declared array in C.

Answer (score 0):

**SPI**
I'm using two functions in my AVR projects, which are working for me. But currently no interrupt support.

*My SPI send function:*

```
void spi_master_send(uint8_t *data, int len)
{
    int i;
    
    if (!data)
        return;
    
    if (len < 1)
        return;
    
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        SPDR = data[i];
        
        while (!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)))
            ;
    }
}
```

The base code from my code is the same as your `SPI0_exchangeData()`. Your function should also work in your project.

*My SPI receive function:*

```
void spi_master_recv(uint8_t *data, int len)
{
    int i;
    
    if (!data)
        return;
    
    if (len < 1)
        return;
    
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        /* send dummy */
        SPDR = 0xFF;
        
        while (!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)))
            ;
        
        data[i] = SPDR;
    }
}
```

To receive data over SPI on AVR you must send a dummy byte. The SPI implementation on AVR is a shift register.

**LTC2983**
I haven't used the LTC2983 at this time. But I have some suggestions for this device.

*First:*
Are you sure, you use the correct SPI mode for this device? There are four modes for SPI. See this [description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface#Mode_numbers) for more information. I don't checked the correct mode for this device. But you can find it in the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/2983fc.pdf) (SPI timing diagram - page 11) from the device.

*Second:*
You set the incorrect data order. The LTC2983 use a MSB data order (Most-significant-bit first. -> See the datasheet - page 15)

*Third:*
You sending `10`, `20`, `30` in a loop in your code. `10` isn't a correct SPI command for reading the `LTC2983` memory (register file).

Valid commands are:
`00000011b` -> `0x03` -> Read from device memory (register file)
`00000010b` -> `0x02` -> Write to device memory (register file)
`XXXXXX0Xb` -> NOP (No operation)

To read the device memory, first send `0x03` then the address what you want to read. A possible example:

```
#define LTC2983_RD    0x03   /* Command read */
#define LTC2983_CSR   0x0000 /* Command status register as example */

uint8_t data_cmd[3];
uint8_t data_out[1];

data_cmd[0] = LTC2983_WR;
data_cmd[1] = LTC2983_CSR << 8;
data_cmd[2] = LTC2983_CSR & 0xFF;

/* Select LTC2983 here */
spi_master_send(data_cmd, 3);
spi_master_recv(data_out, 1);
/* Deselect LTC2983 */
```

With this (pseudo) code you should be able to read the command status register of the LTC2983.

To write to the device, send `0x02` first, then the address and then the value what you want to write.

```
#define LTC2983_WR    0x02   /* Command write */
#define LTC2983_CSR   0x0000 /* Command status register as example */

uint8_t data_cmd[4];

data_cmd[0] = LTC2983_RD;
data_cmd[1] = LTC2983_CSR << 8;
data_cmd[2] = LTC2983_CSR & 0xFF;
data_cmd[3] = 0x42;

/* Select LTC2983 here */
spi_master_send(data_cmd, 4);
/* Deselect LTC2983 */
```

With this (pseudo) code you should be able to write `0x42` to the LTC2983.

For details you can refer the datasheet.